# apache vhost, loosing defaut routing

Tags: apache, routes, vhosts

i'm on centos 6, apache,
after installing apache, when i type my server as URL i get my index.html wich is under /var/www/html.

now i start using VirtualHost and this is my conf:

```
VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin xxx@xxx.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site
     ServerName www.xxx.net
     ServerAlias xxx.net
     ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/site/error.log
     CustomLog /var/log/httpd/site/out.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

as a result when i go to www.xxx.net i get my index.html which is under /var/www/html/site and that's what i want But when i go to my server ip as URL the server redirect me to www.xxx.net.

i wana keep my server ip point on /var/www/html/index.html !!!
any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

so i get it after some test,
solotion : 
uncoment this line

```
#NameVirtualHost *:80
```

and add a new VirtualHost for the default route conf before like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin xx@xxx.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html
     ServerName 212.212.212.212
     ServerAlias 212.212.212.212
     ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/gobal/error.log
     CustomLog /var/log/httpd/gobal/out.log common
</VirtualHost>
```